# Why does Firefox fire two requests for embedded swfs?

Tags: flash, http, firefox, embed, swfobject

When a swf is embedded in a page and is *not* cached locally in the browser, two requests for the swf are fired by the browser. [Here is a simple example](http://www.dweebd.com/examples/double-swf-request/).

The first request returns an expected `200 OK`, and the second request triggers a `304 Not Modified` after the first request has completed, indicating the file is now cached locally.

Why is this 2<sup>nd</sup> request fired and how can I prevent it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this can also be triggered by running Firebug - try checking your browser requests using LiveHTTPHeaders (or some other http sniffing app like Charles) while you have Firebug disabled.

Comment: Disabled firebug and only a single request was fired.
http://www.dweebd.com/examples/double-swf-request/single-request.png

Answer (score 2):

I think I figured it out.  I read the bug reports for Firefox more carefully, and this looks to be caused by AdBlock Plus, which I have installed.  First, I verified that the bug still occurs with your updated page, and reproduced it a second time.  Then, I disabled AdBlock Plus and tried the same test.  The double request was no-longer happening.  So if you have that extension installed, or perhaps a similar extension, that may be the cause.

[This](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=438830) is the bug report about the plugin being double-instantiated, and [this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=467520) is the bug report for the fact that AdBlock Plus causes it.

Comment: I think if you're only seeing one request you may simply have a cached swf.  Have you verified that the one request you're seeing is a 200 OK?  I see double requests and do not have AdBlock Plus (or any weird plugins installed)

http://www.dweebd.com/examples/double-swf-request/no-weird-plugins.png

Comment: Which version of Firefox are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I just verified that this happens for me, as well.

At first, I thought this was due to a bug with Firefox.  See FAQ question #16 on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/swfobject/wiki/faq).  The bugs they reference appear to be fixed, however.

So then I looked at some of my own web sites that embed SWFs using SWFObject 2.2.  The double-GET did not occur.  I think the difference is that in my code, I'm calling swfobject.embedSWF in the `<head>` of the page instead of the body.  Putting the script in the head is what the SWFObject 2.2 documentation recommends (this is a bit of a departure from older versions of SWFObject).

So here's what I'd try if I were you:

1. Remove the google.load("swfobject", "2.2") and include the SWFObject script directly.
2. Move your swfobject.embedSWF code into the head of your page.

Comment: Even with this updated example which includes swfobject directly and invokes the embed call in the document's <head>, I still see the double request.

http://www.dweebd.com/examples/double-swf-request/embed-in-head.html